# How to call a handler from another handler deploying an Alexa Skill?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, handler, alexa-skills-kit

Hello everyone,

i am working on an Alexa Skill at the moment and I have the problem, that I need to call a handler from another one.

I read several posts but there was no clear answer to my problem. I have a handler "AskForEmployeeInformation_Handler" which deals with several intents which answer several questions about a person. But if the user only says the surname or name instead of the full name then Alexa prompts out if there are persons which match to the given name. The user should now say one of the proposed names. While saying this name another handler "SetName_Handler" is called, which sets the chosen name as a session attribute. Now I want to call in the return statement the "AskForEmployeeInformation_Handler" again because it includes the whole logic to prompt out the wanted informations.

I saw some solutions to call the handler like you can see in the following code and the logic was executed but Alexa did not say anything and do not prompt the answer to the user.

Do you have an idea what I can do to solve the problem?

Thanks for your help.

```js
const SetName_Handler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput){
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    return sessionAttributes.event === 'AskForEmployee_Name' || sessionAttributes.event === 'AskForPhoneNumber_Name' || sessionAttributes.event === 'AskForRole_Name';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    let say = '';
    let slotValues = getSlotValues(request.intent.slots); 
    console.log('***** slotValues: ' +  JSON.stringify(slotValues, null, 2));

     //save person for the session - maybe for further questions
     sessionAttributes['employeeSurname'] = slotValues.employeeSurname.resolved;
     sessionAttributes['employeeName'] = slotValues.employeeName.resolved;

     handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes); 

     return AskForEmployeeInformation_Handler.handle(handlerInput; 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to separate the logic out of your handlers.  I have never seen the need to call another Intent's `handle` method from another, and I find that this would add complications and odd errors.

The flat IntentHandler way of doing things is a recipe for disaster once your skill needs to know about session states and context (for example, what the user was doing previous to this IntentHandler being invoked).

Instead, you might find the Dialog Interface way of confirming slots to be exactly what you are looking for: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html

Check out this article for a good overview of why/how to manage state and context in Alexa apps: https://medium.com/hackernoon/lessons-learned-moving-from-web-to-voice-development-35daa1d301db